# Экспорт в Word. Не строится график когда активация просрочена

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, активация

```
WordEngine.InlineShape objShape = doc.InlineShapes.AddChart();
WordEngine.Chart TheChart = objShape.Chart;
TheChart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Core.XlChartType.xlXYScatterSmooth;  // xlXYScatter
TheChart.HasLegend = false;
 
ExcelEngine.Workbook wb =  TheChart.ChartData.Workbook;
 
wb.Windows[1].Visible = false;
//wb.EnvelopeVisible = false;
//    wb.Application.Visible = false;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
//    
ExcelEngine.Worksheet dataSheet = wb.Worksheets[1];
dataSheet.Cells.Clear();
 
ExcelEngine.Range tblRng = dataSheet.get_Range("A2", "B" + (chartTable.Measures.Count + 1));
 
int i = 2;
 
foreach (var measure in chartTable.Measures)
        {
        ((ExcelEngine.Range)dataSheet.Cells.get_Range("A" + i.ToString())).FormulaR1C1 = measure.Amper;
        ((ExcelEngine.Range)dataSheet.Cells.get_Range("B" + i.ToString())).FormulaR1C1 = measure.Volt;
        i++;
        }
 
TheChart.SetSourceData("=Лист1!$A$2:$B$" + (chartTable.Measures.Count + 1).ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.XlRowCol.xlColumns);
```

Когда активированно все работает нормально. А когда активация просрочена, то идут непонятные ошибки. Объект сам создается, он заполнен какими-то данными по умолчанию, но как только дело доходит до попытки его заполнить данными - начинаются ерроры. Пробовал AddChart2 - результат такой же.

Comment: ну могу предположить что это ограничение самого майкрсофт офиса

Comment: Плесни себе рому и вопрос решится. Такие вопросы лучше самому майкрософту задавать, какого черта их неактивированный продукт работает через зад. :) Ну а потом, _"начинаются ерроры"_ - ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: Я бы проверял активацию и выдавал ошибку до того как построить график